# How to handle unreliable connection with rospy?

Tags: ros, wireless, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im running ROS on a AUV that connects wirelessly to a pilot computer. The AUV runs roscore and the pilot computer runs a few nodes to send commands and display its state. When the AUV loses connection everything stops working. If I kill all nodes on the pilot computer before the connection is lost it works fine so Im guessing this is because it gets stuck trying to publish to the pilot computer.

Is there a way to gracefully handle a lost connection between nodes using rospy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163146/how-to-handle-unreliable-connection-with-rospy?/) by [gudjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/17816/gudjon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By default, rospy publishers are blocking, and a blocking publish call won't return until the underlying TCP socket succeeds or times out. You can change this by specifying the queue size to the rospy publisher.

The original bug report for this is [ros_comm #169](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/169) and [the fix](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/pull/308) is released into Hydro and later releases.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gudjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/17816/gudjon/) on 2014-05-14**:
Thanks, adding queue_size=1 seams to fix my problem in most cases. I'm still having problems with one node that uses action lib but I think I can work around that.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-05-14**:
If the rospy implementation of actionlib doesn't support setting the queue size yet, you should probably open a bug letting them know about it.